# priority in textviews inside a table row

Tags: android, textview, android-relativelayout

i have one question about the textviews..

i have one table row in code, which includes one image view and two textviews..
|_| textview1 textview2.

the image view has android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
and the second textview has android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

the problem is when i write a big text in the first text view then it goes over the second textview..I don't want to put one particular number as the width for the first textview.Any idea how can i write big text in first textview and don't overlay the second textview??Something like priority against textviews?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/icon"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:src="@drawable/icon_code_contact" 
      android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <RelativeLayout
     android:id="@+id/secondlayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon" >

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/title"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textStyle="bold"
      android:singleLine="true" />

 </RelativeLayout> 


 <RelativeLayout
     android:id="@+id/thirdlayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
   android:layout_marginRight="25dip" >  

        <TextView
      android:id="@+id/stamp"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
   android:singleLine="true" />  



 </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: don't know if it has to do with the problem, but the two inner layouts seem to be useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that you didn't give a right limit to your middle textview. once you've removed the two inner `RelativeLayout` (and moved their layout params to the `TextView` they contain), you can do that by adding `android:toLeftOf="@id/title"` to the second `TextView`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for your problem:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10px"
        android:text="This is text 1 for testing!">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is text 2"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10px">
    </TextView>

    </TableRow>
```

Note: Text2 may shift to the next line if it exceeds the max width of the layout.

Hope it helps you. Let me know if anything could have been done better.